# Pass environment variable on AWS Elastic Beanstalk for Spring Boot App using Jasypt

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jasypt

I was deploying my Spring Boot Application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. My web app is using Jasypt, so in the application.properties file, I wrote down `jasypt.encryptor.password=`, currently the password in this file is empty, I want to pass the password as a variable on AWS Beanstalk's configuration.

When testing locally, I used `java -jar myapp.jar --jasypt.encryptor.password=1234` in command line, and it ran successfully. However, when deploying on AWS, I added `jasypt.encryptor.password` in environment properties and set its value to 1234, the app failed to run. The log said I cannot set the password as empty. So, at this point Beanstalk did not read the environment property I just set. But it can really read the properties later because I tested it after setting another property and used GET API to print it.

My question is: how to make Elastic Beanstalk run/read the environment properties at the beginning? In other words, how to make EB run `java -jar myapp.jar` with `--jasypt.encryptor.password=1234`attached?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*Procfile* can't use environment variables. Use a shell script to start the application instead of invoking `java -jar` directly in *Procfile*.

**Procfile:**

```
web: /bin/sh start_server.sh
```

**start_server.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_OPTS='-Djasypt.encryptor.password=1234'
exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar myapp.jar
```

references: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html